# Trying to run selenium tests and getting this

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber

```
tduhamell-m2-7290479:staging_tests tamduhamell$ cucumber features/112_Calendar.feature
cannot load such file -- pry (LoadError)
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/tamduhamell/automation/staging_tests/features/support/env.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:107:in `load'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/glue/registry_and_more.rb:107:in `load_code_file'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:144:in `load_file'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:85:in `block in load_files!'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `each'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:84:in `load_files!'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:272:in `load_step_definitions'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:68:in `run!'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:34:in `execute!'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/cucumber-3.1.2/bin/cucumber:9:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/bin/cucumber:23:in `<main>'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with selenium, it's saying `cannot load such file -- pry` so you need to install the `pry` gem

Comment: thank you, I installed it and now getting this error tduhamell-m2-7290479:staging_tests tamduhamell$ cucumber features/112_Calendar.feature
Warning is not a class (TypeError)
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/structured_warnings-0.2.0/lib/structured_warnings/warning.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'

Comment: I am not sure but looking at this gem [structured_warnings](https://github.com/schmidt/structured_warnings) it says _Versions of structured_warnings before v0.3.0 are incompatible with Ruby 2.4+_. And I can see here you're using Ruby 2.4 and the gem version 0.2.0

Comment: Thank you, updated that gem and now getting a different error uninitialized constant Attempt::StandardWarning
Did you mean?  StandardError (NameError)
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/attempt-0.2.1/lib/attempt.rb:13:in `<class:Attempt>'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.9/gems/attempt-0.2.1/lib/attempt.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `require'
/Users/tamduhamell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.9/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:130:in `rescue

Comment: I am not sure. It looks like the [attempt](https://github.com/djberg96/attempt) gem hasn't been updated for a couple years, doesn't have a ton of community usage, and doesn't give you much functionality that is difficult to implement by hand. Most likely what I would do is refactor the code to remove that dependency, unless you want to dig into the gem's code to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Actually, what version of `attempt` do you have? It looks like the issue may have been fixed. Maybe bump the `attempt` version to the most recent

Comment: You could also try running this codebase with an older version of Ruby (ideally the same version that was used when the library was written), if you don't want to deal with updating all these dependencies.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: Well, you seem to have Ruby 2.4 installed using RVM. This program stands for "Ruby Version Manager" and can be used to install and switch between multiple versions. I recommend checking out [their docs](https://rvm.io/rvm/basics)